# get CPU usage of a VM (linux) using java

Tags: linux, java, kvm

Is there an API for Java in getting the CPU usage of a VM in KVM? I want to know how I could get the CPU usage of a guest (from the host's perspective) using Java.

Also, does anybody know where I could find the source of `virt-manager` so I could learn how it gets/computes the CPU usage it displays in Virtual Machine Manager?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the methods in Interface OperatingSystemMXBean be adapted to what you are looking for.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any Java APIs which expose KVM but the source for virt-manager is accessible here in the official Git repo.

- https://git.fedorahosted.org/git/virt-manager.git

Additionally I'd look to the [libvirt API](http://libvirt.org/api.html) for interacting with KVM or any other virtualization technology. Specifically there are [Java bindings to the libvirt API](http://libvirt.org/java.html).

Comment: Thank you sir. I've been to that website (Git repo of virt-manager) a lot of times since I've been researching for weeks but I couldn't manage to understand how the site works. Is it all right if you could briefly explain how it works? Thanks a lot sir.

Comment: @user3752288 - here's a link to the latest trunk version of the code base: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/virt-manager.git/snapshot/virt-manager-master.tar.gz. It's tarred up for easier download.